# Or tools cp_model know which constraint is failing

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

tools for a scheduling problem with a cp_model.
I've added 8 constraints to the model and in cases the solution status returned is Infeasible, my question is if there is a way to know which constraint couldn't be fulfilled and was the reason to return INFEASIBLE as a status.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple methods:

- Remove them 1 by 1 ?
- Try to inject a known solution.
- Minimize the size of the problem to help debugging.

If you can rewrite the model, you can look at the [assumptions sample](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/assumptions_sample_sat.py).
using the same model, you can try to maximize the number of enforced constraints (instead of using assumptions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i want to know if there is something that helps to indicates which constraint is not satisfied as a reponse from the algorithm to help the user to know where is the problem in there input data, of course if this is possible.